# Delete first 10 rows using for loop

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

I was asked in an interview, "how to delete the 1st ten rows using a for loop"?

I answered that, "it does not sound logical as using a for loop would not be necessary to delete 1st ten rows". Was I right?

And if I had to give the query, what would be the answer?

```
for i in 1..10
   loop
    delete from table where rownum=1;
   end loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 1..10
   loop
    delete from table where rownum=1;
   end loop
```

The code is wrong.
Yes, it is not logical to delete rows in a for loop, but the question is still confusing.
If you are saying you want to delete the first ten rows fetched by query
no matter in what order then you can use something like this.

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE key IN (SELECT key from mytable FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY);
```

Using for loop does not make sense but still you can do something like this.

```
DECLARE
  key dbms_sql.number_table;
BEGIN
  SELECT EMPNO BULK COLLECT INTO key FROM emp;

  FOR i IN 1..10
  LOOP
    DELETE FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO = key(i);
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use SQL and the `ROWID` pseudo-column to directly correlate between the `SELECT` statement where the `ORDER`ing occurs to the `DELETE` statement using the pointer to the row (rather than having to correlate on a primary key in the table):

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE  ROWID IN (
  SELECT   ROWID
  FROM     table_name
  ORDER BY value
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
)
```

If you want to use a `FOR` loop then you can do the same thing in PL/SQL by using `BULK COLLECT` to store the `ROWID` values:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE rowid_t IS TABLE OF ROWID;
  rowids rowid_t;
BEGIN
  SELECT ROWID
  BULK COLLECT INTO ROWIDS
  FROM   table_name
  ORDER BY value
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
  
  FOR i IN 1 .. rowids.COUNT LOOP
    DELETE FROM table_name
    WHERE ROWID = rowids(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*(Note: You want to loop to the size of the collection rather than naively looping to the maximum value of 10 as there may not be 10 rows in the table to delete.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0972561d9f9845d3e533f4b1296c2c72)*

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop statement:

```
create table test_tbl
    as select level num
         from dual
      connect by level<=100
/  
begin
for rc in (select rowid rid 
             from test_tbl 
            order by num fetch first 10 rows only)
   loop
     delete from test_tbl where rowid=rc.rid;
   end loop;
   commit;
end;  
/
```